# Difference between \mathit and math-style = TeX

Tags: math-mode, fonts, unicode-math

I would like to know what the difference is between `\mathit` and setting `[math-style = TeX]` regarding italics in math mode.

This code will explain it better

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[math-style = TeX]{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

    \[ \mathit{\rho} \rho \]

\end{document}
```

Only the latter showing up with an "italic" style (TeX math-style).

If an unicode math font such as STIX Two Math is loaded, the same will happen, but this time a cross inside a rectangular box will show up as `\mathit{\rho}`

Here's the code for said scenario

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[math-style = TeX]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

    \[ \mathit{\rho} \rho \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\symit{\rho}` However, it is already the same as `\rho`

Comment: The `unicode-math` package provides the directives `\symit` ("symbol italic") and `\symup` ("symbol upright"). These directives may be used to override the defaults set by the math style (`TeX`, `ISO`, `french`, or `upright`) that's in effect. (The default math style is `TeX`.)

Comment: Why does `\symit` not show italic numbers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to know what the difference is between `\mathit` and setting `[math-style = TeX]` regarding italics in math mode.

There's a huge difference between (a) loading the `unicode-math` package and selecting a `math-style` (e.g., "TeX" or "ISO") that employs italics for lowercase Latin and Greek letters and (b) using `\mathit`. (Aside: For more information on the math styles provided by the `unicode-math` package, see section 5.1 of the package's user guide.)

Using `\mathit` operates quite independently of the chosen math style. Using `\mathit` can generate outcomes which may be unexpected -- at least at first. This is because the `\mathit` directive accesses its letters from the text font, *not* from the math font. This is by design. According to David Carlisle's comment (see below), `\mathit` should be used for multi-letter identifiers, such as the names of variables. For variable names, it's better to use italics from the text font, rather than "true" math-mode italics.

Consider the table below, which shows the four available math styles (ISO, TeX, french, and upright), with lowercase and uppercase Latin and Greek letters. The math font is set to `Stix Two Text`, while the *text font* is set to `Calibri`. I chose a sans-serif text font to make the difference between text and math fonts glaringly obvious.

Confirming what I asserted above, observe that the `\mathit` output, shown in the final column, does *not* employ letters from the math font family. Instead, it quite evidently employs letters from the text font family.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\myarray[1]{\par\noindent% 
% Structure of table:
  %col. 1: math style
  %col. 2: math mode, lowercase Latin letters
  %col. 3: math mode, uppercase Latin letters
  %col. 4: math mode, lowercase Greek letters
  %col. 5: math mode, uppercase Greek letters
  %=col. 6: output of \mathit
    $\begin{array}{@{}p{1.2cm} >{$}p{1cm}<{$} *{3}{>{$}p{0.6cm}<{$}} l }
    #1 & abcffi & XYZ & \alpha\beta\gamma & \Phi\Psi\Omega
    & \mathit{abcffi} \\ % <-- final column uses "\mathit{...}"
    \end{array}$}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Calibri}[ItalicFont="Calibri Italic"] % sans-serif text font
%% or: \setmainfont{Stix Two Text} 

\begin{document}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[math-style = ISO]
\myarray{ISO}

\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[math-style = TeX]
\myarray{TeX}

\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[math-style = french]
\myarray{french}

\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[math-style = upright]
\myarray{upright}
\end{document}
```

Comment: nice answer but not sure why you say that the fact that `\mathit` uses a text italic is of historical interest. that was always (and still now) the main point of the command and why it should be used for multi-letter identifiers in preference to the math italic font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Many thanks for this comment! I was actually unaware until just now of the real reason for *why* `\mathit` uses glyphs from the text font rather than from the math font. (Until now, I was never sure why `\mathit` behaves so differently from the plain-TeX `\mit` directive!) I will edit the paragraph in question accordingly.

Comment: By design, plain tex `\it` has a definition `\ifmmode math version \else text version\fi` latex splits that and has separate  `\mathit` and `\textit` commands.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Thanks - I just learned something new again! :-)

Comment: No italic numbers though, why?

Comment: @Suppboi - I'm not sure what you're referring to. If it's to the output of `\mathit`, then italic numerals will indeed be generated. (Check it out for yourself if you're so inclined.) For the "regular" math material, though, TeX follows the typographic convention that numerals in math mode are *always* set using upright, not slanted, glyphs. This holds irrespective of the chosen math style (ISO, TeX, french, or upright). By design, the math style affects only the absence or presence of slant in Latin and Greek letters.